# How to set child's chart values files?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I consider using the helm structure with common chart, chart per service using it, and umbrella chart. Like in this [example](https://github.com/CodeJjang/helm-microservices-example).
But then I create `values-local.yaml` `values-stage.yaml` and `values-prod.yaml` for each service.

And if I run charts separately, I can pass `helm install -f values-prod.yaml`, but when I run my umbrella chart how do I make all it's  subcharts use `values-prod.yaml` from their repos?

Answer (score 1):

So if your directory structure looks like this:

```
    ├── umbrela_chart
    │   ├── charts
    │   │   ├── chart1
    │   │   ├── chart2
    │   │── values 
    │   │   ├── values-prod.yaml
    │   │   values.yaml
```

and your values-prod.yaml config for the umbrela_chart looks like:

```
  chart1:
    chart1_key:
      chart1_sub_key: value1  

  chart2:
    chart1_key:
      chart1_sub_key: value1
```

then when you deploy your umbrela_chart the sub-charts would automatically use the values defined in values-prod.yaml. So the important step is to define all the values for the chart "chart1" under the key "chart1" and the same for the other charts.

Comment: The point is that I want to place each value file to the appropriate subchart folder. Placing all the values in one file will be pretty messy, when amount of services increases.